# Bazel fails to run command, by hand it works. How to debug?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to compile tensorflow in a bit difficult environment (Centos 6.2 with a load of "own" compilations).

A lot of problems I have solved already, but the one baffling me is a SWIG error. I run with "--verbose_failures" and I can see the command that bazel tries to run:

```
(cd /home/../.cache/bazel/_bazel../[long-hexa]/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
exec env - \
bazel-out/host/bin/external/swig/swig -c++ ...
```

It fails with "Exit 1: swig failed:  error executing command.

However, when I `cd` to the mentioned directory and run the mentioned bazel-out/../swig command it succeeds! What I have understood is that this probably is a problem of bazel trying to sanitize the environment.

How can I go to debug this? Is there a way to show what environment variables bazel is using?

Comment: try disabling sandbox mode, https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#sandboxing and visit https://blog.bazel.build/2016/03/18/sandbox-easier-debug.html if that helps

Comment: Look at your own environment variables, get rid of most of them. Remove things like $HOME/bin from $PATH. See if you can reproduce the problem on your normal environment.

Comment: Does the command pass with `env - bazel-out/...` too?